# Need help with java portable

Tags: java, portable

I want to code java on my work computer. I tried installing eclipsce portable and JDK portable from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net). I tried running eclipsce and it simply did not detect the java. my question is, is there a way to use eclipsce portable with java portable? also can you please describe everything in detailed?
Sorry for any mistakes is spelling or grammer. English is not my strong point.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, so I have to post it as an answer, even though I have not tried it, sorry.

Since you say

> I tried running eclipsce and it simply did not detect the java

I just searched for `eclipse set path to jdk`. Thr first result is an S.O question, [Setting JDK in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635563/setting-jdk-in-eclipse) and has an accepted answer with 154 upvotes, so that ought to help.

> Here is the complete sequence in Eclipse Luna:
>
> - Right click your project > properties.
> - Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click Edit…
> - Select "Workspace Default JRE"
> - Click "Installed JREs"
> - If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK too)

If that doesn't help, try further results of the search. Good luck, and welcome to Stack Exchange.

Btw, since you are new, I will say that  if this works, please click the tick to accept the answer. Doing that will show others who read the question in future that it works. Add comments if any problems.

Comment: So which software are you recommending here, Mawg? :/

Comment: Lolx! (And upvote). I am recommending the s/w which he is using, Eclipse. Obviously, I forgot which site I was on, as I failed to remind him that his question is off-topic here. Could you please migtrate this to SuperUser (not S.O, as it contains no code)? Thanks (and embarrassed apologies).